# r jug package not able to run, need local hosting of r functions

Tags: r, api, http

I'm trying to replicate the toy example found here:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/jug-easily-create-r-apis/

When I load the jug package, and run the script, my R console just seems to run continuously, thus I not able to attempt the second part of the code where I submit the curl request.  I basically want to create a few functions that accept HTTP input, and host the functions locally. What am I missing?

See the screenshot image of [my R console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFcmW.png)

Comment: open up another R session, or do the curl request on the command line

Comment: Thanks, sckott. I started a new RStudio session, but I'm still not able to get the curl command to work as in the example. I've tried the following in the new session, and none seem to work. Any ideas? library(curl)
curl ("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
curl("127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Bart")
curl("http://127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Bart")
curl 127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Bart
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Bart

Comment: dont know - i'd probably try a different tool, e.g, https://github.com/trestletech/plumber

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to http://127.0.0.1:8080? Do it while the script is running (as per your screenshot). It should prompt you the response of the function. In any case, I had similar issues with jug, so I recommend using plumber instead.